# Bind list of ImageSource to list

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I have this class:

```
 public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    }
```

I have this ObservableCollection of cars:

```
  private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return _cars; }
        set
        {
            _cars = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Cars");
        }
    }
```

In my view, i would likte to bid this collection to a listview and display the image and the name:

```
<ContentView Padding="5">
      <ListView x:Name="cars"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

              <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
  </ContentView>
```

But only the Name gets displayed. What am i missing here? Any tips on how to bind the image to a listview?

Thanks!

UPPDATE:
The error seems to be memory-related:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-25 15:18:30.159 E/mono-rt (25597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
03-25 15:18:30.159 E/mono-rt (25597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
03-25 15:18:30.159 E/mono-rt (25597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:378)
03-25 15:18:30.159 E/mono-rt (25597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
```

I can usually see the first item in the list before the exceprion occurs. Any Ideas of how to solve this?

UPDATE2:

Im using Xlabs Camera.function to take the image:

```
public async Task<MediaFile> TakePicture()
        {
            Setup ();

            ImageSource = null;

            return await _Mediapicker.TakePhotoAsync (new CameraMediaStorageOptions {
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front, MaxPixelDimension = 20
            }).ContinueWith (t => {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Status = t.Exception.InnerException.ToString();
                }
                else if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Status = "Canceled";
                }
                else
                {
                    var mediaFile = t.Result;

                    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);


                    return mediaFile;
                }

                return null;
            }, _scheduler);
        }
```

Is it maybe possible to somehow in the above method make the image smaller before it gets saved to the devices disk?

Answer (score 0):

In Model Class , **Use BitmapImage as datatype for Image Property.**
ImageSource datatype is used only to set image source for an ImageBrush Control

```
public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Image { get; set; } // Propery type should be BitmapImage
    }
```

**In case, If the BitmapImage class is missing in PCL**, you can use the below one:

Just Replace the

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}"></Image>
```

with

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100">
<Rectangle.Fill>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}"></Image>
</Rectangle.Fill>   
</Rectangle>
```

and keep your model class as you have given.

Comment: Thank you very mucg for answering. Unfortunatley in my PCL, where I have the model. I do not have acess to The BitMap-Class. Is there someway around this problem?

Comment: Add this code in using section `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`

Comment: That class does not exist in the PCL so it cannot be added. Thank you

Comment: I have made an edit on answer, which will suits for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this does not seem to be legal Xaml in Xamarin. My problem seem to have to do with lack of memory: